# No logs are written to /var/log

Tags: log, syslog

I have a problem, that no logs are written to /var/log.

```
-rw-r-----  1 syslog adm  6.4M May 21  2014 syslog
-rw-r-----  1 syslog adm  5.7M May 21  2014 daemon.log
-rw-r-----  1 syslog adm  494K May 21  2014 auth.log
```

But date and time is configured properly

```
Tue Apr 28 19:38:56 CEST 2015
```

It seems that I made a dist-upgrade 21 May of 2014. And since then I have no logs written. My system is Ubuntu 14.04 (no GUI). It has been running for 132 days without reboot.

Other log files like MySQL or nginx are up to date. Only system logs don't work.

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Ok, I found solution somewhere else:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall rsyslog
```

It seems rsyslog was removed itself at some point.

Answer (score 11):

have you started/restarted the systemlogs deamon?

```
    sudo service rsyslog start
```

or

```
    sudo service rsyslog restart
```

this should work. This problem came for me also, i restarted this deamon, now its working fine.

Comment: `systemctl enable rsyslog`

Answer (score 3):

Not really directly related to the question, but had similar problem on WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux): system was not writing logs to syslog, rsyslog restart was not completing successfully.

Windows version: `Windows 10 Pro 1909`
Command: `sudo service rsyslog restart`

> - Stopping enhanced syslogd rsyslogd [ OK ]
> - Starting enhanced syslogd rsyslogd rsyslogd: set SO_TIMESTAMP failed on '/dev/log': Invalid argument [v8.32.0]
>     rsyslogd: imklog: cannot
>     open kernel log (/proc/kmsg): No such file or directory.
>     rsyslogd:
>     activation of module imklog failed [v8.32.0 try
>     http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2145 ]

**Solution**:
From https://askubuntu.com/a/615473/497599

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall rsyslog   ()
```

And `start` after that! `restart` is not working.

```
sudo service rsyslog restart
```

Starting enhanced syslogd rsyslogd [ OK ]

https://gist.github.com/0x49D1/596d457921034e9c18e5e1052a4ad515

Comment: This seems to be an issue with imklog and /proc/kmsg -- https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/534 but I think you need to run WSL2 to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Could try this in case something's mis-configured with `rsyslog`, at least before trying a full reinstall:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure rsyslog
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by uninstalling rsyslog `sudo apt-get purge rsyslog` and then reinstalling it `sudo apt-get install rsyslog`. In my case the permissions and ownership of the files were all correct but the syslog file was empty and all the logs were going into uncategorized.log

Comment: Please note that the accepted answer at [https://askubuntu.com/a/615473/283721](https://askubuntu.com/a/615473/283721) performs the same function