# Is it expected to not have `rsyslog` installed after a fresh install of ubuntu server?

Tags: ssh, openssh, rsyslog

Is it expected to not have `rsyslog` installed after a fresh install of ubuntu server?
If yes, where do logs that go to `/var/log/auth.log` actually go then?

Here is what happened: I was looking for `/var/log/auth.log` file and I could not find it.
My search leads me to [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615457/no-logs-are-written-to-var-log) where people say that `rsyslog` is the issue.

I realized I did not even have `rsyslog` installed after my fresh ubuntu server install (I selected the minimized installation).

```
> sudo service rsyslog status
Unit rsyslog.service could not be found.
```

After installing `rsyslog`, the `/var/log/auth.log` file started to exist.

Why didn't Ubuntu install rsyslog? Seems like a pretty important piece to have.

What am I misunderstanding?

- Ubuntu server 22.04.4 LTS
- Used the "minimized" option during install

Thanks

Comment: I used the "minimized" option during install and it's for Ubuntu server 22.04.4 LTS

Comment: Doing more research, it looks like everything is moving to `journalctl` on modern versions so that might be just it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **minimized** image does **not** contain `rsyslog`.  Your experience is expected.

You are right that `journald` is still installed as part of `systemd`.  The `/dev/log` file has pointed to `journald` for several LTS releases now.  The default settings for `journald` include `ForwardToSyslog=yes`, which is why `rsyslog` still processes logs when installed.

A lot of packages you probably would expect in a Linux system are not installed when using the "minimized" image.  When the 22.04 installer was released I compared the packages within the images to see what is missing in the "minimized" image.

```
root@ubuntu-server:/# diff <(dpkg --admindir=/media/minimal/var/lib/dpkg -l | grep ^ii | sort) <(dpkg --admindir=/media/filesystem/var/lib/dpkg -l | grep ^ii | sort) | grep ii | awk '{print $3}'
apt-utils
bash-completion
bc
bind9-dnsutils
bind9-host
bind9-libs:amd64
bolt
bsdextrautils
busybox-static
byobu
cloud-initramfs-copymods
cloud-initramfs-dyn-netconf
command-not-found
cron
debconf-i18n
distro-info
dmidecode
dosfstools
ed
eject
ethtool
file
fonts-ubuntu-console
friendly-recovery
ftp
fwupd
fwupd-signed
git
git-man
hdparm
htop
info
init
install-info
iptables
iputils-ping
iputils-tracepath
irqbalance
landscape-common
less
libarchive13:amd64
libatasmart4:amd64
libblockdev-crypto2:amd64
libblockdev-fs2:amd64
libblockdev-loop2:amd64
libblockdev-part-err2:amd64
libblockdev-part2:amd64
libblockdev-swap2:amd64
libblockdev-utils2:amd64
libblockdev2:amd64
libefiboot1:amd64
libefivar1:amd64
liberror-perl
libestr0:amd64
libevent-core-2.1-7:amd64
libfastjson4:amd64
libflashrom1:amd64
libfribidi0:amd64
libftdi1-2:amd64
libfwupd2:amd64
libfwupdplugin5:amd64
libgcab-1.0-0:amd64
libgpgme11:amd64
libgpm2:amd64
libgudev-1.0-0:amd64
libgusb2:amd64
libip6tc2:amd64
libjansson4:amd64
libjcat1:amd64
libjson-glib-1.0-0:amd64
libjson-glib-1.0-common
liblmdb0:amd64
libmagic-mgc
libmagic1:amd64
libmaxminddb0:amd64
libmbim-glib4:amd64
libmbim-proxy
libmm-glib0:amd64
libmspack0:amd64
libnetfilter-conntrack3:amd64
libnewt0.52:amd64
libnfnetlink0:amd64
libnftables1:amd64
libnftnl11:amd64
libnl-3-200:amd64
libnl-genl-3-200:amd64
libnspr4:amd64
libnss3:amd64
libnuma1:amd64
libparted-fs-resize0:amd64
libparted2:amd64
libpcap0.8:amd64
libpipeline1:amd64
libpython3.10:amd64
libqmi-glib5:amd64
libqmi-proxy
libslang2:amd64
libsmbios-c2
libsodium23:amd64
libtcl8.6:amd64
libtext-charwidth-perl
libtext-iconv-perl
libtext-wrapi18n-perl
libtss2-esys-3.0.2-0:amd64
libtss2-mu0:amd64
libtss2-sys1:amd64
libtss2-tcti-cmd0:amd64
libtss2-tcti-device0:amd64
libtss2-tcti-mssim0:amd64
libtss2-tcti-swtpm0:amd64
libudisks2-0:amd64
libutempter0:amd64
libuv1:amd64
libvolume-key1
libxmlsec1-openssl:amd64
libxmlsec1:amd64
libxslt1.1:amd64
locales
logrotate
lshw
lsof
lxd-installer
lxd-agent-loader
man-db
manpages
modemmanager
motd-news-config
mtr-tiny
nano
netcat-openbsd
nftables
open-vm-tools
overlayroot
parted
pastebinit
patch
powermgmt-base
psmisc
python3-automat
python3-bcrypt
python3-commandnotfound
python3-constantly
python3-debconf
python3-debian
python3-gdbm:amd64
python3-hamcrest
python3-hyperlink
python3-incremental
python3-newt:amd64
python3-openssl
python3-pexpect
python3-ptyprocess
python3-pyasn1
python3-pyasn1-modules
python3-service-identity
python3-twisted
python3-zope.interface
rsync
rsyslog
run-one
sbsigntool
screen
secureboot-db
sosreport
strace
tcl
tcl8.6
tcpdump
telnet
time
tmux
tnftp
tpm-udev
ubuntu-advantage-tools
ubuntu-minimal
ubuntu-server
ubuntu-standard
udisks2
ufw
update-manager-core
update-notifier-common
usb-modeswitch
usb-modeswitch-data
usb.ids
uuid-runtime
vim
vim-common
vim-runtime
vim-tiny
whiptail
zerofree
```

The manifest files for the cloud-images may provide more recent differences between the images

- https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/jammy/current/
- https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/minimal/releases/jammy/release/

I believe the images are created by scripts in the [live-cd](https://git.launchpad.net/livecd-rootfs/tree/) repository, and the packages installed are defined by the [server and server-minimal seeds](https://ubuntu-archive-team.ubuntu.com/seeds/ubuntu.jammy/).

A couple of the comments may provide additional context.

- [ubuntu-server-minimal.catalog-in.yaml](https://git.launchpad.net/livecd-rootfs/tree/live-build/ubuntu-server/ubuntu-server-minimal.catalog-in.yaml?id=e0b79f12531e46a849681d62b2634b79b9ce3192)

  > This version has been customized to have a small runtime footprint in
  > environments where humans are not expected to log in.
- [server-minimal](https://ubuntu-archive-team.ubuntu.com/seeds/ubuntu.jammy/server-minimal)

  > This seed is approximately the smallest set of packages that could be
  > called "an Ubuntu server".